A movie about aliens living underground
So I'm trying to find a movie, in which an alien species digs a tunnel and lives underground. In the movie we can see at the beginning a little boy outside a house, and suddenly the ground collapses and he falls into a tunnel, and later an alien takes him. The aliens can paralyze people and if I remember correctly there's some kind of survivor in the tunnel complex with an axe who fights the aliens. 
I'm trying to find what that movie is because it gave me a recurrent nightmare when I was a kid, and it's quite important to me to find what it was.

How old is this movie? And is it in English? It sounds a bit like Invaders from Mars from '53 (and its remake from '86), but some of the details don't fit.

when were you a kid?

sounds a little like CHUD, except they're not aliens, they're mutated humans...and it opens with a woman walking a dog. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.H.U.D.#Plot

@BenPlont Why not post it as an answer? Even if you're not 100% sure about due to mutants rather than aliens (might be hard to differentiate for a kid after all).

@Mario I would, but, I'm waiting for a response to the when "were you a kid question". If nathan was a kid in the 50s 60s or 70s, it's back to the drawing board.

Around what year did you see it or was it made? There was a Doctor Who episode similar to that. Aliens living under Earth, starts to cause problems, DW negotiates a new detente - but I think its one of the more recent seasons.

@Jeff-InventorChromeOS That happened in series 5, so too recent. It's also missing the axe part.

@Mario Well, I gave a comment from a couple years ago and an answer from 54 years ago. Hopefully one of them fits :)

I'm thinking of The Tommyknockers, except I don't remember if the aliens are still alive in the miniseries.

I might as well put up Invaders from Mars as an answer because it actually features aliens living in underground tunnels and a boy going through a hole in the ground. The 1953 version is about a boy named David who witnesses a flying saucer landing in a sandpit behind his house; he later sees his young neighbor sucked into a hole in the sandpit. He manages to convince a psychologist that he's telling the truth and as they investigate the area, they're sucked into the underground tunnels and taken by the aliens.
The 1986 version has the same basic plot, only David voluntarily investigates the tunnels and he's helped by a school nurse this time. The aliens in that version looked like this:

The aliens in the 1953 version:

Both versions also had a 'brainy' alien (a huge brain in 1986 and a guy with a big head in 1953).

Is it Tremors (1990)? 
"Natives of a small isolated town defend themselves against strange underground creatures which are killing them one by one." 
It's got the underground creatures who are terrorizing a town, including a teenage boy, shown in second picture below



My favorite movie, but that's not it. OP said the aliens take the boy and paralyze them. The tremors (ass blasters, snakoids, etc) just kill and eat you.

+1 Good points. Though I've noticed that sometimes the OP's initial recollections aren't 100% accurate.

Also in Tremors (at least the first movie, not sure about the other 3) they do not go into the tunnels to find a surviver.

The Time Machine (1960) by HG Wells featured alien-like creatures that lived underground and preyed on humans above ground.  The protagonist makes his way into the tunnels to rescue his love interest and is eventually successful. 
There's no little boy falling into a tunnel though. The "aliens" stage raids to capture "humans" and take them below ground. 


The movies in question is called The Mole People circa 1956. It had been bothering me too, same kid nightmares. It's a blend of the Sleestaks from the 1972 TV series Land Of The Lost and the 1953 Invaders From Mars. The visual reference of laying down and heads being covered with flour sacks prior to abduction might ring true.
